# What verb tense to use in the provided context?

Tags: tenses

> It could not have easily been the case that Alan **formed/has formed/had
>   formed** the view that X, and yet X was not true.

Which of the verb forms are correct in the above sentence: formed, has formed, or had formed?

Answer (score 1):

'Have easily been' is the past perfect. And something occurred before that, namely, something formed.

Thus the pluperfect is required in order to make the action of 'forming' precede the existence of 'the case'.

Thus it should read :

> It could not have easily been the case that Alan had formed the view that X, and yet X was not true.

Comment: So, shouldn't you change "was" into "had been" too?